# Can't Install Mojave because of file system error: Object map is invalid

Tags: mac, hard-drive, high-sierra, filesystem, mojave

I wanted to upgrade macOS High Sierra to Mojave but installation failed with this error:

> File system verify or repair failed.

Using Recovery Mode I tried First Aid from Disk Utility and it failed again with the following details:

> Checking the object map.
>
> error: omap entry (oid 0x13e319): invalid ov_paddr (2251799814186955)
>
> Object map is invalid.
>
> The volume /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely.
>
> File system check exit code is 8.
>
> Restoring the original state found as mounted.
>
> File system verify or repair failed.
>
> Operation failed.

After that I tried **fsck -fy** command from single-user mode but that didn't work and the result was the same.

I can't clean install my macbook right now. Is there any other way to fix the problem? maybe by fixing the object map somehow or by using any other third party tool?